# How to fix a print error in python for a multiple choice quiz?

Tags: python

I apologize in advance if a topic like this has already been made, if so, please link me to it, thank you.

So, I have been trying to create a multiple choice quiz in python (yes, very iconic) but when I try to run it, I get a syntax error which is common I suppose, however, it seems to have an issue with the print variable:

```
print ('QUESTION 1: WHAT IS A NON-MOVING OBJECT CALLED?\n')

print ('A. Solid')

print ('B. Still object')

print ('C. Stationery')

print ('D. not moving')

print ('E. Stationary')

print ('')

Q1answer = "E"

Q1response= input('Your answer : ')

if (Q1response != Q1answer):

    print ('Sorry! It appears that your answer is incorrect! A non-moving object is called Stationary.')

    print ('Better luck next time!' , answer)

else:

    print ('Well done! ' + Q1response + ' is correct!')
    score = score + 1

    print ("Even I got that one right!"


**print("Your current score is ' str(score) + ' out of 10")**

print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

the print variable for showing the score you get out of 10 doesn't seem to work.
Am I doing something wrong?

It'd be a great help if someone could tell me, I'm not very good at coding.

Comment: `print("Your current score is "+ str(score) + " out of 10")`

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis in `print ("Even I got that one right!"`

Comment: Oh okay, thank you!

Comment: You have more than one error in the code. You should narrow it down to the one line which has a syntax error and then if you still don't understand what the error is, you should post just that one line and ask for help. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Your current score is %d out of 10" %score)
```

Take a look at [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) for details on formatting and inserting other types of data into a printed string.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at that

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are a few problems with your code.
Firstly, you did not define what score is i.e. you need to say score = 0 first. Secondly, there is a missing parenthesis in print ("Even I got that one right!"
Thirdly the way you did the score sentence could be improved. Overall, correcting the errors it would look like this:

```
print ('QUESTION 1: WHAT IS A NON-MOVING OBJECT CALLED?\n')
print ('A. Solid')
print ('B. Still object')
print ('C. Stationery')
print ('D. not moving')
print ('E. Stationary')
print ('')


score = 0
Q1answer = "E"
Q1response= input('Your answer : ')

if (Q1response != Q1answer):
  print ('Sorry! It appears that your answer is incorrect! A non-moving object is called Stationary.')
  print ('Better luck next time!' )
else:
  print ('Well done! ' + Q1response + ' is correct!')
  score = score + 1
  print ("Even I got that one right!")
print("Your current score is ",score, "out of 10")

print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

Hope this helps!!